# where should i put my CSS files ? Symfony 3.0

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

i need some help, i am a begginer, i start learning Symfony few days ago but i found this problem, i dont know where should i put my css files, and i am asking for help ..
so here is my twig file : ( in folder src/../views/user)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('essai.css') }}" />

{% endstylesheets %}
</head>
</html>

<h1>
  Hello
</h1>
```

and my file css "essai.css" is in web/bundles/framework/css

```
h1 {
     color: red;
    }
```

Thanks for any help.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is simple you define follow path:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('essai.css') }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

-

```
'bundles/app/css/*'
```

And your file on this path

```
web/bundles/framework/css
```

now you have to solutions:

1. you change the path in your template from 'bundles/app/css/*' to 'web/bundles/framework/css/*'

OR

1. you change put your css file in the folder 'bundles/app/css/'

---

The solution of @kunicmarko20 is right too.

Or read the documentation:
symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html that link from @adam187

Comment: it still doesnt work, maybe i have an other problem, thank you anyway, i will take a look at the documentation, Thanks again

Comment: Hello again, i fixed my problem, i just wanted to say Thank you again, have a nice day :)

Comment: was the solution right or what kind of fix does solve your problem?
If my support was right you can mark my answer as right ;) 
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Your css and js should be in your `web/` folder and that is where `asset()` is looking for them so you should change:

`{{ asset('essai.css') }}` => `{{ asset('bundles/framework/css/essai.css') }}`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, do you anything else that may cause a problem, because i tried your code and it still doesnt work, Thank you friend

Comment: @adam187 did I say something wrong? `Store your assets in the web/ directory.` as this is a line from that URL.

Comment: @TaouBen is there any kind of error on the server side or in your browser console? maybe you need to refresh browser cache

Comment: i cleared my cache, and havent seen any error, but thank you, i will try again, thank you kunicmarko20 :)

Comment: Hello again, i fixed my problem, i just wanted to say Thank you again, have a nice day :)

Comment: @kunicmarko20 No, i just posted link to documentation with full information about this subject :)

Comment: @adam187 I guess I should have posted that also, I thought I did not give a good answer and that it was a link for me, sorry for misunderstanding.